# Plot unconnected graph in igraph

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I have an unconnected graph that I  plot with `fruchterman-reingold` layout in `igraph`

```
require(igraph)
er_graph <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 5/20)+erdos.renyi.game(100, 5/20)
coords<-layout.fruchterman.reingold(er_graph)
plot(er_graph,layout=coords, vertex.label=NA)
```

Plot Example :
[image: plot example]

The result was two distant clusters.
I wish to decrease the white area in my plot.
Is there a way to scale the coordinate in order to decrease the space between the clusters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be an easy way to do this in one of the layout functions, but you can also directly change the node coordinates after creating the layout. If you look at `coords`, you can see it's just a matrix of node coordinates. You can use the cluster labels to move the two node clusters closer together programmatically:

```
require(igraph)
require(dplyr)

er_graph <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 5/20)+erdos.renyi.game(100, 5/20)

# Make layout reproducible
set.seed(40)
coords <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(er_graph)

# Original graph
plot(er_graph,layout=coords, vertex.label=NA)
```

[image]

Move clusters closer together: First, we add the cluster labels to the coordinates and set a parameter `f` for what fraction of the distance between clusters we want eliminate. Then we subtract from each node `f` times the difference between the mean coordinates for that cluster and the mean coordinates over both clusters.

```
# Add cluster labels to coords
coords = data.frame(coords, clust=clusters(er_graph)$membership)

# Move closer by a fraction "f" of mean distance between clusters
f = 0.6

# Shift each node closer to the overall center of mass of the node
coords = coords %>% 
  mutate(X1 = ifelse(clust==1, X1 - f*(mean(X1[clust==1]) - mean(X1)), X1 - f*(mean(X1[clust==2]) - mean(X1))),
         X2 = ifelse(clust==1, X2 - f*(mean(X2[clust==1]) - mean(X2)), X2 - f*(mean(X2[clust==2]) - mean(X2))))

# Convert coords back to original matrix form
coords = as.matrix(coords[,1:2])

# Re-plot graph
plot(er_graph,layout=coords, vertex.label=NA)
```

[image]